# Unknown Objective-C runtime 'microsoft'

Tags: windows, visual-studio, clang, objective-c-runtime, winobjc

I'm trying to compile an app with WinObjC. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.6 and WinObjC prerelease v0.2.180221 from NuGet.

The very first source file it tries to compile, and every subsequent one fails with the error message:

> `clang.exe : error : unknown or ill-formed Objective-C runtime 'microsoft'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You seems trying to use side loaded clang compiler, that not gonna work unfortunately, since for WinObjC have been used modified clang with custom ObjectiveC runtime added.

To build your project successfully, you must add latest WinObjC nuget packages of version v0.2.180221-dev-20180516000001 to your project along with this https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinObjC.Compiler/ compiler package, it includes proper clang forked from original clang v6.0.1. Supported VS version is **v15.4.5-15.8.9**

**UPDATE 1**

To use latest Visual Studio starting from v15.9 up to the current VS2019 v16.X, you might find useful [this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/WinObjC/issues/2884) with guide how to modify your project to make it run.